# Creating SSH Credentials for Agent in Jenkins Credentials Plugin Results in Error and Stacktrace

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-plugins

I just installed Jenkins LTS using Docker and wanted to add an agent with an SSH key. When I try add an SSH credential, I get "A problem occurred while processing the request." and this error message in the console:

```
2023-06-01 15:04:29.423+0000 [id=12]    WARNING h.i.i.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler#handleException: Caught unhandled exception with ID 3558d2ea-2ed3-4e7a-bb18-36f43e69e259
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The frontend sent an unexpected list of classes (["com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl","org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubAppCredentials","com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey","org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.FileCredentialsImpl","org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl","com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.CertificateCredentialsImpl"]) rather than an expected single class. See 
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/views/table-to-div-migration/ for more information.
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:748)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate interface com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials from {"stapler-class":["com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl","org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubAppCredentials","com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey","org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.FileCredentialsImpl","org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl","com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.CertificateCredentialsImpl"],"$class":["com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl","org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubAppCredentials","com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey","org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.FileCredentialsImpl","org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl","com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.CertificateCredentialsImpl"]}
```

I tried latest, tried a completely fresh install: nothing. Same error. I expect it to work.

I'm using the recommended plugins: https://pastes.dev/gOXfvs4hu2
This is my docker-compose.yml: https://pastes.dev/lS2adT5KBT